Elegant way to mix Move constructor with Base class's Copy assignment operator
Problem Explanation
Here's what I understood so far during last two month studying about Move semantics:

Move constructor implicitly insert SomeClass::operator=(const SomeClass&) = delete at end of class definition, disabling Copy assignment operator

Such behavior is to enforce Rule of 5, where either Move constructor or Move assignment operator is used - all following 5 should(or subsect of those in some cases) be implemented:

Move Constructor
Copy Constructor
Move operator=
Copy operator=
Destructor




However, if I want to re-use assignment operators from base(or parent/super) class - simply putting
using SomeBaseClass::operator=;

in child class that implements Move Constructor seems like insufficient, as we established just before - compiler implicitly inserts this at end of child class's definition when Move Constructor is defined.
class SomeClass: public SomeBaseClass {
public:
    SomeClass(SomeClass&& other);
    using SomeBaseClass::operator=;
    ...

    // Compiler: let me help you!
    SomeClass& SomeClass::operator=(const SomeClass&) = delete;
}

...Which seems to have much higher priority when matching, shadowing using ~~:operator=, making following an error:
class SomeClass a, b;

a = b;  // Use of deleted func!



Question
Obviously writing operators on subclasses again that internally just wraps base class's operators should and do work. Just 3 lines more to each subclasses:
// using void to give up ability to chain like a = b = c
void SomeSubclass::operator=(const SomeSubclass& other) {
   SomeBaseClass::operator=(other);
}

...But it feels like it defeats purpose of using inheritance in first place. Is there any better alternative ways?


Here's MRE representing this behavior (Compiler Explorer Live):
#include <iostream>


class Derived;


// Interface class to reuse & enforce specific set of operations
// over multiple sibling subclasses
class SomeInterface {
protected:
    // Function to allow subclass usage inside predefined operations
    virtual Derived& get_derived() = 0;

public:
    // destructor / move / copy assignment defined to satisfy Rule of 5 in subclasses

    virtual ~SomeInterface() = default;

    // Giving up ability to do a = b = c
    void operator=(const Derived& other);
    void operator=(Derived&& other);
};
// ...Now I'm not sure if this count as interface class, still doesn't have member data tho!


// Subclass implementing Interface
class Derived : public SomeInterface {
protected:
    int some_data;

    Derived& get_derived() override;

public:
    Derived(int data) : some_data(data) {}
    Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept;
    Derived(const Derived& other);

    // Some data accessors
    int& get_data() { return some_data; }
    const int& get_data() const { return some_data; }

    // Using predefined operators provided by interface
    using SomeInterface::operator=;

    // No errors if we define wrapper
    //void operator=(const Derived& other) {
    //    SomeInterface::operator=(other);
    //}
};


// --- Implementations ---

Derived& Derived::get_derived() {
    return *this;
}

Derived::Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept {
    std::swap(some_data, other.get_data());
}

Derived::Derived(const Derived& other) {
    some_data = other.get_data();
}


void SomeInterface::operator=(const Derived& other) {
    get_derived().get_data() = other.get_data();
}


int main() {
    Derived a(2);
    Derived b(19);

    a = b;  // <-- Use of deleted function Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived&)

    std::cout << a.get_data() << std::endl;
}



Detailed Context (Optional Read)
Such structure seems weird for sure, here's logic behind why I came up with it:

There's Class A, B, C. And I want (almost) all the A, B, C's functions are available in Class D and E.
Each Class A, B, C defined 2~30 member functions, with few thousands of code behind it.

If we accomplish this by copying functions in class A, B, C into D & E, we'll need to copy paste thousands of lines with manual small, let a lot of modifications on implementations to make it work.
This obviously will be real painful to maintain as any single change in any of class's functions requires 5 class to be updated to maintain uniform user-side interface (not thru polymorphism).

Actual case of this is a Json library I'm reinventing wheel for.
(I'm aware of Json for modern C++ - just at this place I'm not even allowed of MIT/Unlicense licensed open source libraries)

JsonValue, JsonArray, JsonObject's feature should be available in JsonArrayProxy & JsonObjectProxy, to support expressions like:
arr[0]["some_key"].append({"key": "val"})
Which each subscript operators return proxy classes To distinguish read-only access and write-only access.

I managed to implement these by manual copy-pasting, but due to maintainability issues I decided to create an Interface classes that doesn't define their dataclasses, but defines all operations that should be commonly shared.
// some mock-up class structure

// Interfaces
class JsonStringfierInterface;

class JsonValueInterface: public JsonStringfier;
class JsonObjectInterface: public JsonStringfier;
class JsonArrayInterface: public JsonStringfier;

class JsonProxyInterface
    : public JsonValueInterface,
    public JsonObjectInterface,
    public JsonArrayInterface;

// Implemntation
class JsonValue: public JsonValueInterface;
class JsonObject: public JsonObjectInterface;
class JsonArray: public JsonArrayInterface;

// Proxy of JsonValue, returned by JsonObject[char*]
class JsonValueObjectProxy: public JsonProxyInterface;

// Proxy of JsonValue, returned by JsonArray[int]
class JsonValueArrayProxy: public JsonProxyInterface;

So the stuffs works, even with the trickest JSON format I can think of works fine - however, was curious if there was better way to do this without wrapping copy assignment operators.

Even Extra Detailed Context
Here's Extra detail of full class diagram to help clarify my intention X behind this question Y in case this is XY problem.
Tried to organize my best.

There's just so many operations that overlaps each other, for JsonValue JsonValueObjectProxy JsonValueArrayProxy (Which is what this question's Class A, B, C was about) so that those 3 classes are visually same to users using this library in their code.
JsonObject obj = LR"({ "k": "val" })";

// Subscript returns JsonObjectProxy
obj["key"] = "insert/update situation";
obj["key"] == "access only situation";

// .value(idx) / .at(idx) returns JsonValue&
obj.value("key") == "access only situation";
obj.value("key") = JsonObject(LR"({ "inner key": 2.19E+17})");

// user doesn't need to know if it's returning proxy or not
obj["key"]["inner key"] == 1.0;
obj["key"].value("inner key") == 20;

obj["key"]["inner key"] = { 1, 2, "3" };
obj["key"].value("inner key") = { "4", 5, nullptr };
...

Relying on Interface class where it defines one virtual data getter(get_val, get_const_val in image) and build up operations with it solved the problem, but to see this 'solution' still needed wrapper on subclasses - I wondered if I can also eleminate that.

don't have a solution on top of my head, but i can stand behind what compiler is trying: your base class operator= returns BaseClass& so there is room of error, hence it wants you to be more explicit about your intention and opt into the eventual downcasting.

@haleyk Oh I forgot to edit that out will edit that soon when I'm back at PC! Right now, it returns void (as in MRE). Basically traded off a = b = c  ability to prevent more complexity.

no worries, i assumed the wrong return type :P

Possible solution: https://godbolt.org/z/7Y9h87xnx NB: You have to change the signature of the base class' copy ctor. Still fairly ugly IMHO.

Please try to make your MREs more M. I've skipped the last part of the question, because I am too lazy.

@haleyk ngl originally let it return baseclass type unintentionally, then changed at last moment in MRE but not in descriptions - thanks for pointing it out.

@Super-intelligentShade Thanks, will try out asap when I'm back! And about MRE I did split sections to 3 just for that reason; Saw some people wants to see X of the XYZ problem, some prefer it short. So to satisfy both I just split sections so only top parts are needed to understand issue fully.

i do think your best shot is to have an macro that generates those 3 lines alongside. the compiler is better-off defaulting its deleted to handle the general case with multi-inheriatnce

@Super-intelligentShade That surely is a way, but sadly this is being designed as Library(in detailed context section) so asking them to use static casting everytime writing into JSON data structure seems to be a bit troublesome. Thanks for suggestion though!

@haleyk yeah so far seems so, can't find way to let compiler consider the using brought baseclass operator first on my end. Since it's merely 3 line per class, and I have 5 actual class so only 15 lines of code - 1 * 5 line with marcro seems to be only bet so far that beats it in practicality and readability. Gotta let this open for while to see if there's any more possibilities too.

using doesn't "overwrite" special member of derived. Not really related to deleted move-assignment

@Jarod42 Ah I see, then do baseclass's special members brought via using still get considered by compiler as overload candidate?

You should be following the rule of zero, not the rule of five. Your proxy class doesn't own any resources.
Getting rid of all the special members solves your problem.

Had to edit so deleted and rewriting comment, oops. Unless I am hallucinating I'm not seeing any of operator= overload! And that is very much needed as I need to support various assignment like JsonValue = JsonValue JsonValue = std::variant. I do need that to implement same logic on JsonValue JsonArrayProxy (Proxy of a value in JsonArray) JsonObjectProxy (Proxy of a value in JsonObject) class so that by implementing only get_derived() in subclasses - all 3 gets identical functionality without manual copy paste. I'll rename proxies shown as example to clear confusion.

After studying more now I (probably) am getting more confused; Since interface class itself doesn't define data itself so I should follow Rule of zero. On the other hand I should define & implement special members to it keep DRY rule, so I don't have to copy paste same logic with slight variation least 3 times for operator=, let alone expanding to other special members & user-defined member functions would add least one thousand of lines estimated
